# what is wrong with this traffic light javascript code?

Tags: javascript

this code is to switch between pictures (traffic lights) and then make it go back to the start again. the first image is working fine however the others will not come up.

```
<head>
<img id="red" src="A452 Images/red light.png" width="255" height="300" />
<button onclick="fnnextimage()">change image</button> 
</head>

<body>
<script>
var imgarray=[];

imgarray[0].src = "A452 Images/red traffic light.png";
imgarray[1].src = "A452 Images/yellow traffic light.png";
imgarray[2].src = "A452 Images/green traffic light.png";

function fnnextimage(){

    var lightchange = 1;

    lightchange = lightchange+1;

    if(lightchange=3){
        lightchange=1};

    document.getElementById('red').src=imgarray[fnnextimage]
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: The most "correct" answer to this question is that you must learn how to use the debugger in your browser.  There are a number of issues in your code that would become apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains three errors:

1. `lightchange` should be a global variable, so you need to declare it above the function (as you do with `imgarray`):

   ```
   var imgarray=[];

   imgarray[0].src = "A452 Images/red traffic light.png";
   imgarray[1].src = "A452 Images/yellow traffic light.png";
   imgarray[2].src = "A452 Images/green traffic light.png";

   var lightchange = 1;

   function fnnextimage(){
   ```
2. `if(lightchange=3){` should be `if(lightchange == 3) {`. Use `=` for assignments and `==` for equality checks.
3. You cannot use a function as an array index: `imgarray[fnnextimage]` should be `imgarray[lightchange - 1]` (array indices start with zero).

In conclusion, this should work:

```
var imgarray = [];

imgarray[0].src = "A452 Images/red traffic light.png";
imgarray[1].src = "A452 Images/yellow traffic light.png";
imgarray[2].src = "A452 Images/green traffic light.png";

// Changed: lightchange is now global
var lightchange = 1;

function fnnextimage() {
    lightchange = lightchange + 1;

    // Changed: compare to 3 instead of assigning 3
    if(lightchange == 3){
        lightchange = 1;
    }

    // Changed: Use correct array index
    document.getElementById('red').src = imgarray[lightchange - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `var lightchange` is not a global variable. To fix it, do following:

```
var imgarray=[],lightchange = 1;

imgarray[0].src = "A452 Images/red traffic light.png";
imgarray[1].src = "A452 Images/yellow traffic light.png";
imgarray[2].src = "A452 Images/green traffic light.png";

function fnnextimage(){

    lightchange++;

    if(lightchange==3)
        lightchange=1;

    document.getElementById('red').src=imgarray[lightchange-1];
}
```

Comment: This still does not fix the problem with the line `lightchange=3` and you still use `fnnextimage` as an array index although it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `fnnextimage` function, `lightchange` is first set to `1`, then incremented (to `2`). Its value ends up the same each time that function executes.

(*Tip: When a function doesn't do what you expect, `console.log(variableName)` is a quick way to see what is in `variableName` at any given time. That's a faster way to debug than asking Questions on SO.*)

When the code tries to compare `if(lightchange=3)`, it actually *sets* the value instead of *evaluating* the value. [Use `==` in conditionals.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

`imgarray[fnnextimage]` is trying to access the index with variable `fnnextimage` which doesn't exist — that is a function name, not a variable name.